# Evitar que un lector de código de barras escriba en el control activo

Tags: c#, windows

Tengo desarrollada una aplicación en C# que captura el momento en que un lector 
de códigos de barras conectado a la PC realiza una lectura (la idea es automatizar el proceso de lecturas). La app funciona correctamente, pero lo que necesito hacer es que al momento de que el lector realice la lectura de un código, no se escriba el código en el textbox/control/ventana/word/notepad/etc etc en el que esté puesto el foco al momento de realizar la lectura.

Entiendo que esto debe ser más una configuración del lector o del sistema operativo, ya que mi app trabaja en un hilo de ejecución diferente al de la lectura del lector.

Hay forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Un lector de códigos de barras es igual que un teclado, envía la información que lee al dispositivo al que está conectado y este es el que decide que hacer. Necesitarías programar un *driver* específico para hacer lo que pretendes, pero ¿a donde enviarías entonces la información?  Actualmente ¿De donde lee tu aplicación el código?

Comment: Mi aplicación está interceptando el momento de la lectura usando RAW_INPUT (a través del API de Windows).

Comment: Intentalo conectandolo via serial, de esta manera puedes mandar los datos leidos al textbox u otro objeto especifico que tu decidas. Depende que Scanner utilices, por ejemplo en Symbol en las instrucciones de uso biene un codigo de barras con el cual se pone en modo serial solo lo escaneas y listo.